FlaskForm not rendering
I have register.html, index.html and base.html as below however, when i visit the route /register, the form does not appear. The below code also includes register route and RegistrationForm. I would appreciate if someone can identify why the form is not being rendered
---------------Register.html------------------------

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2 class="mt-4">Register</h2>

  <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('main.register') }}">
  
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.username.label(class="form-label") }}
      {{ form.username(class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.email.label(class="form-label") }}
      {{ form.email(class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.password.label(class="form-label") }}
      {{ form.password(class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-label") }}
      {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}

---------------Register.html------------------------

---------------Index.html---------------------------

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Home {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class="mt-4">Recipes</h1>

<!--This section uses 'Card' Section of the Bootstrap framework-->
{% for recipe in recipes.items %}
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ recipe.dish_name }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ recipe.recipe[:100] }}</p>
            <a href="{{url_for('recipe', id=recipe.id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Recipe</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<!--This section uses 'Card' Section of the Bootstrap framework-->


<!--This section uses 'Pagination' Section of the Bootstrap framework-->
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if recipes.has_prev %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('main.index', page=recipes.prev_num) }}" aria_label= "Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %} 
        {% for page_num in recipes.iter_pages() %}
            {% if page_num %}
                <li class="page-item {% if page_num == recipes.page %} active {% endif %}">
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{  url_for('main.index', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
               </li>
            
               {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#">...</a>
                    </li>
            {% endif %}    
        {% endfor %}      
        {% if recipes.has_next %}  
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('main.index, page=recipes.next') }}" aria-label="Next">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>               
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
<!--This section uses 'Pagination' Section of the Bootstrap framework-->
</nav>
{% endblock %}

---------------Index.html---------------------------


---------------Base.html---------------------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %} Recipe App {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Recipe App</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" typ="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('new_recipe')}}"> New Recipe </a>
                    </li>
                    {% if current_user.is_admin %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('admin_recipes')}}">Admin</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}"></a>                    
                    </li>    
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.login') }}">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.register') }}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}     
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% with messages=get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} mt-3">{{ message }}</div>            
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

---------------Base.html---------------------------

---------------Routes.py---------------------------

@main.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
       return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
   
    form = RegistrationForm()
    print(f"Form data: {form.data}")
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Form is valid")
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been created! You are now able to log in', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.login'))

    else:
        print("Form is not valid")
        print(form.errors)

    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)

---------------Routes.py---------------------------

---------------Forms.py---------------------------

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(),EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign up')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That username is taken. Please choose a different one.')
        
    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That email is taken. Please choose a different one.')

---------------Forms.py---------------------------

I am expecting the simple RegistrationForm should appear in which users will registry themselves but it does not render.
OUTPUT ----
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2024 09:09:14] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Form data: {'username': None, 'email': None, 'password': None, 'confirm_password': None, 'submit': False, 'csrf_token': None}
